# mqtt-react-hooks Subscriber stops working after one message

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, mqtt, redux-toolkit

I have a simple react app using mqtt-react-hooks and redux. I want to update my redux store each time a new message is received by a Subscriber.

Subscriber.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect} from 'react';
import { useSubscription } from 'mqtt-react-hooks';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../features/item/hooks';
import { addItem } from '../features/item/item-slice';

const Subscriber = () => {
  const { message } = useSubscription('queue');
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (message && message.message) {
      dispatch(addItem(JSON.parse(message.message)));
    } 
  }, [message]);

  
  return (
        <span>{message}</span>
  );
};

export default Subscriber
```

App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {useAppSelector} from './features/item/hooks'
import { Connector } from 'mqtt-react-hooks'
import Subscriber from './mqtt/Subscriber'

function App() {
  const items = useAppSelector((state) => state.item.items);

  return (
    <>
      <Connector brokerUrl="ws://localhost:9001"
      options={{keepalive: 10}}>
      <div className="item-holder">
        {Array.from(items, ([key, it]) => ({ key, it })).map( (kvp) => { return <div>{kvp.it} key={kvp.key}></div>})}
      </div>
      <Subscriber />
      </Connector>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I remove the `useEffect` from the Subscriber, the message gets received and updated. And I can send as many messages as I want. However, when I call the `dispatch(addItem(...` inside the `useEffect`, it will receive the first message, but ignores all future messages. My mosquitto broker says that the client has closed the connection. It never attempts to reconnect.

I'm very new to react. I have a feeling I'm not doing this right at all. What I really want is a redux store that maintains state based off of messages coming from an mqtt topic. The app has buttons that allows the user to publish messages back to the mqtt broker and change the redux state.

**EDIT**

As requested, here's the addItem code.

```js
import {createSlice, PayloadAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface ItemState {
    items: Item[],
}

const initialState: ItemState = {
    items: []
}

const orderSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'items',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addItem(state, action: PayloadAction<Item>) {
          state.items.push(action.payload);
          
          return state;
        }
    }
});

export const { addItem } = itemSlice.actions;
export default itemSlice.reducer;
```

And the useAppDispatch comes from `./features/item/hooks`

```js
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState, AppDispatch } from './item-store'

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

However, I will add that I got rid of this and used the usual useDispatch and useSelector instead of the "useApp____" versions and got the same result.

I believe the issue lies in the `mqtt-react-hooks` hooks but my react-fu skills are not yet high enough to solve.

Comment: Can you share the code for `addItem` and your reducer code?

Comment: Please also share the `useAppDispatch` that is providing the `dispatch` function. Try to include all the relevant code necessary for us to trace the above code and see/understand all the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a sequence of things happening that is causing `Connector` to rerender and drop the connection, here's what I think is going on:

1. `App` is subscribing to store state, causing it to rerender every time a new message is received.
2. You're recreating your mqtt config object every time `App` renders, because you're passing an object literal `{keepalive: 10}`
3. In [Connector.tsx](https://github.com/VictorHAS/mqtt-react-hooks/blob/master/lib/Connector.tsx#L48) line 48, the `mqttConnect` callback depends on the mqtt options object. React does a referential equality check, sees the options have changed, and causes the callback to be recreated.
4. In [Connector.tsx](https://github.com/VictorHAS/mqtt-react-hooks/blob/master/lib/Connector.tsx#L59) line 59, this causes the useEffect to rerun because the callback changed, which calls its teardown function, which ends the mqtt connection.

To fix it, you should create your MQTT options outside of `App` so that they don't change.

Comment: This was the correct answer! Thank you! I memoized the options to fix the referential equality issue and it now works perfectly! `const options = useMemo(() => {return {keepalive: 10};}, []);` and then `<Connector brokerUrl="ws://localhost:9001" options={options}>`.